# Smallest Packets of Electromagnetic Wave - Confused

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation

I heard that the smallest units of electromagnetic wave packets is a single photon. Why can't we have the electromagnetic wave intensity to be smaller? Since we're changing electromagnetic waves can't we manipulate it to have a smaller amplitudes/intensity? Or is this an impossible thing to do?

Comment: Are you familiar with the [Ultraviolet catastrophe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultraviolet_catastrophe)?

Comment: The amplitude of the electromagnetic field can have arbitrarily low values. This just means that fewer photons are detected.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to do.  As it turns out, there is a fundamental linkage between the frequency of electromagnetic radiation and the smallest amount of energy that can be emitted or detected at that frequency.

This was first determined by experiments, and analysis of the results led to the theory (theories) of quantum mechanics.

Key experiments included measurements of the spectrum of black body radiation (see [Black Body](https://chem.libretexts.org/Textbook_Maps/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Map%3A_Physical_Chemistry_(McQuarrie_and_Simon)/01%3A_The_Dawn_of_the_Quantum_Theory/1.2%3A_Quantum_Hypothesis_Used_for_Blackbody_Radiation_Law)), and measurements of the energy and number of electrons emitted when light of various frequencies and intensities illuminates a metal surface (see [Photoelectric Effect](https://chem.libretexts.org/Textbook_Maps/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Map%3A_Physical_Chemistry_(McQuarrie_and_Simon)/01%3A_The_Dawn_of_the_Quantum_Theory/1.3%3A_Photoelectric_Effect_Explained_with_Quantum_Hypothesis)).

All that said, it is still possible to manipulate photons to change their energy.  For example, a photon that reflects from a moving mirror can gain or lose frequency (and energy); but the relationship between the final energy and frequency will always be $E = h\nu$. ($E$ is the energy in the photon; $h$ is Planck's constant, and $\nu$ is the frequency of the photon)